# How to .sort based on multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have an array `items` like so:

```
items.sort(function(a,b) {
});
```

a & b have the following properties:

```
a.suggested (true, false, undefined)
a.meta.member_count (int .. 1 or more, undefined.
```

I would like to sort items as follows:

1. all items that are not suggested. Either false or undefined
2. member_count, highest # first,
3. Then show any suggested === true

Is sort the right way to go about this? How can I make this happen in the sort function?

Answer (score 0):

This will sort by the 'suggested' value, putting false/undefined values above true values. After that, it will sort by meta.member_count (highest first).

```
items.sort(function(a,b) {
    if (a.meta.member_count === undefined) { x = 0; } else { x = a.meta.member_count;}
    if (b.meta.member_count === undefined) { y = 0; } else { y = b.meta.member_count;}

    if (a.suggested !== true) {
        if (b.suggested !== true) {
            n = x - y;
            return n < 0 ? 1 : n > 0 ? -1 : 0;
           }
        return -1;
    } else if (b.suggested === true) {
        n = x - y;
        return n < 0 ? 1 : n > 0 ? -1 : 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
});
```

The key in this case lies in converting the undefined member_count values to 0 so we can do math with them.

Also, when sorting numbers using the JavaScript sort() function, make sure to do math on the actual numbers and then use an if statement to return 1, -1, or 0. If you return the difference between the values directly, it will compare the values as strings instead of numbers.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/55nocg1j/)